# Compiling vertex shader program fails

Tags: opengl, glsl, shader, opengl-3

I'm doing my first steps with OpenGL and stumbled upon a problem  in my vertex shader program:

```
#version 330 core
layout (location = 0) in vec3 aPos;
uniform mat4 inputTransform;
void main()
{
   gl_Position = inputTransform * vec4(aPos, 1.0);
}
```

compiles and works well, but when I change the first line to

```
#version 130 core
```

because I'm bound to use OpenGL 3.0 at max, it first complains about the "location" statement. When I remove it, the remaining error message for the line

```
layout in vec3 aPos;
```

is

```
ERROR: 0:2: 'in' : syntax error syntax error
```

What's wrong here - how do I have to declare input variables in this version of the language?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Input layout qualifiers have been added in GLSL version 1.50 wich corresponds to OpeneGL version 3.2

See [OpenGL Shading Language 1.50 Specification; - 4.3.8.1 Input Layout Qualifiers; page 37](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL/specs/gl/GLSLangSpec.1.50.pdf).

An input layout qualifier consists of the keyword `layout` followed by the *layout-qualifier-id-list*.
It is not sufficient to remove the *layout-qualifier-id-list* alone, you have to remove the keyword `layout` too:

```
in vec3 aPos;
```

The syntax error is caused by the fact, that it is not a proper syntax, that `layout` is directly followed by `in`.

---

Either you have to ask for the attribute index by [`glGetAttribLocation`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glGetAttribLocation.xhtml) after the program is linked, or you have to specify the attribute location by [`glBindAttribLocation`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glBindAttribLocation.xhtml) before the shader program is linked.